# Firestore query by Object Key

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a series of nested objects in a collection in firestore, that have a key of a UID. I want to query all documents that relate to a user, by checking if their UID is the object key (basically if it exists). This is the model in firestore: 
[image]

and this is how I am currently trying to return the documents:

```
  getAllTenancyOffersByUserId() {
    return this.afs.collection('collection_name', ref =>
      ref.where(`application.members.${this._auth.currentUserId}`, '==', !null),
    );
  }
```

but this returns nothing. I understand that I could just query by that status, however it is constantly updating so will cause problems

Answer (score 7):

The following should do the trick:

```
  getAllTenancyOffersByUserId() {
    return this.afs.collection('members', ref =>
      ref.where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', `${this._auth.currentUserId}`)
    );
  }
```

See the corresponding doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldPath#.documentId

Comment: it is not the document id that I am trying to query by

Comment: Can you indicate, based on your database print screen, on what you want to query?

Answer (score 5):

Actually, what you could do is to filter by any string field that you have in the object like this:

```
.collection("collectionName")
.where("mapArray.map.stringField", ">", "''")
```

the important part here is the string field being; ">", "''"

Comment: Wow thanks. This worked for me as well. If you would like to know whether a key is included in an object, try this. (Just in case, however, if you have a plan to do compound queries, check another solution as we need to add a composite index for compound queries)

Comment: So does the key of a mapped object get persisted as a stringField field in each of those objects?

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is not possible to query whether a object exists or not. I think your idea of querying a field inside your object may be the best bet.

What you could try is querying the date_modified field for anything greater than 1900.

```
getAllTenancyOffersByUserId() {
  return this.afs.collection('collection_name', ref =>
    ref.where(`
      application.members.${this._auth.currentUserId}.date_modified`, 
      '>=',
      new Date('1900-01-01')
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not you add the id to the object? e.g

```
    members: {
      currentMemberId: {
      date_modified:"",
      deposit_type:"",
      status:"pending",
      memberId: "currentMembderId" 
     }
    }
```

and you do your query as: `.collection('members').where('memberId', "==", currentMemberId)`